# Flash the newer version of ROM over the old one on ART environment

Tags: custom-roms, cache, dalvik, lg-g2, art

I've flashed Carbon ROM on my LG G2 (D802) device and when e new Nightly release, I download it and put it on my SD Card and dirty flash it (Only clean Dalvik cache and cache partition). Now I've changed my enviroment from Dalvik ro ART and it seems that everything except nandroid manager is working fine, my question is, when a new Nightly release, what should I do now exactly? should I dirty flash like the other ones? and when I flashed the latest Nightly, what will happen to my environment, will it change back to Dalvik or it will stay on ART environment?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: On most modern 4.4.x based ROMs, you don't have to manually clear the caches, as it's automatically done during the flash anyways.

Comment: @Chahk please post source so people can verify this.Also I need source for: wiping cache wipes dalik too

Comment: [Source](http://forum.cyanogenmod.com/topic/74526-how-do-i-update-cyanogenmod/). Specifically- see 4th paragraph of the 1st post.  Obviously this is for CyanogenMod ROM, but other recently built ROMs that are based on CM or AOSP sources should follow the same logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I got your question correctly then yes yout ART environment should not be changed. The script will run at flashing time will wipe dalvik cache and cache itself and will not touch your personal settings. So you are safe to flash the nightly as a Dirty flash. However I have not flashed any latest aosp KK based rom but it should follow the same procedures as all custom rom does. I flashed many time dirty flash on my current device which is running on stock based custom rom and have no problem at all.

I'll suggest you to make a nandroid and make a dirty flash afterwards so if anything goes wrong you can restore your backup and start from scratch.

Answer (score 1):

It should be identical to flashing when Dalvik is enabled. If the ROM cook packaged up everything correctly, you should be able to "dirty-flash" the nightly builds over the previous ones (assuming you are staying on the same ROM channel.)  I would confirm with the ROM author though.

On the topic of wiping caches, the CyanogenMod's [installation instructions](http://forum.cyanogenmod.com/topic/74526-how-do-i-update-cyanogenmod/) specifically state:

> Contrary to popular belief, there is no need to wipe ANYTHING when you
>   update CM. This includes your cache partition, your dalvik cache, and
>   your battery stats. While wiping these won’t hurt anything, you can
>   increase the time it takes to boot up CM after you install the update.
>   Android is smart enough to manage both your cache and dalvik cache
>   without you intervening, and wiping your battery stats does absolutely
>   nothing to help with your battery life (the file is only used to
>   provide the raw information to provide the stats and graph in Settings
>   -> Battery) – it is actually wiped automatically every time your device is charged to 100%.

Of course you should always have a recent backup via recovery in case things start to go wrong.

Comment: @Chank thank you, but what will happen to my Runtime, will change back to Dalvik, or it will remain on ART?

Comment: @user3157358 Still ART